# could not convert string to float: '2019-10-16'

Tags: python, numpy

I get a value error when I want to load the following data set.
I skipped the first line because it says "don't take titles - first line" in some sources. But again it gave an error on another line.

[image: dataset]

```
from numpy import loadtxt
path = r"C:\Users\emre.yildirim\Desktop\Dominos_Stock_Data.csv"
datapath = open(path,'r')
data = loadtxt(datapath,delimiter=",")
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Date'

```
 from numpy import loadtxt
 path = r"C:\Users\emre.yildirim\Desktop\Dominos_Stock_Data.csv"
 datapath = open(path,'r')
 data = loadtxt(datapath,delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-10-16'

Comment: try `genfromtxt` instead of `loadtxt`

Comment: Check [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html): `dtype` is "Data-type of the resulting array" and by default `float`. `2019-10-16` is not a float. Provide a schema instead or use [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

Comment: @GhostOps thanks but print(data[:1]) gives result as [[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]] why?

Comment: @Cocojombo i think its because not all the values in the matrix are float as the first row has alphabets, so numpy substitutes with nan i guess

Comment: @GhostOps also date is nan. OK but value in the first row, 254.89 seems like 2.5489e+02. Why ? (:

Comment: @Cocojombo i have no idea on that, i tried printing `254.89` in a numpy array, it prints as it is, but when i added some integer like `72814887` it starts to print every other number as like `...e+blabla`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) instead of loadtxt

And also, as the header has text string, numpy substitutes with `nan` (i guess) as the `dtype` is `float` by default

So try `skip_header=1` along with it in the `genfromtxt`

Code:

```py
from numpy import genfromtxt

path = r"C:\Users\emre.yildirim\Desktop\Dominos_Stock_Data.csv"
datapath = open(path,'r')
data = genfromtxt(datapath, delimiter="," ,skip_header=1)
```

Outputs everything excluding the header

Tell me if its not working...